# How do I get each of my class attribututes to display random colors?

Tags: javascript, html, class

Instead of displaying a random color on each class, the console throws me this error

> TypeError: document.getElementsByClassNames is not a function

I've looped the class elements and I saw a few videos on how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Random Color Slot Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slots.css"/>
  <script src="colorSlots.js"> </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Welcome to my random color slot game!</h1>
  <button onclick = "document.getElementsByClassNames('pick').innerHtml='inputNum()'">click to play</button>
  <div>
   <div class="pick" id="one"></div>
   <div class="pick"></div>
   <div class="pick"></div>
   <div class="pick"></div>
   <div class="pick"></div>     
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

const element= document.getElementsByClassName('pick');

let color = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple']
function inputNum(){
    for(i=0; i<element.length; i++){
    element[i]
}
const rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length){
    return 'document.getElementsByClassName("pick").style.'+ rand
}
```

Each `div` tag should display a random color

Comment: The function `.getElementsByClassNames` is called `document.getElementsByClassName`. That's just a typo...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the doc about what a Good Stack Overflow question should contain [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function is not getElementsByClassNames.
getElementsByClassName.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: i figured. I figured out the problem. I needed to use brackets instead.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. 
Attention, propose your code. You can add it by `ctrl + M`

```js
function inputNum() {
  const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.pick');

  const rand = colors.sort(() => .2 - Math.random());

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = rand[i]
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to my random color slot game!</h1>
<button onclick="inputNum()">click to play</button>
<div>
  <div class="pick" id="one"></div>
  <div class="pick"></div>
  <div class="pick"></div>
  <div class="pick"></div>
  <div class="pick"></div>
</div>
```

Second solution

```js
function inputNum() {
  const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'];
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.pick');

  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = colors[rand];
  }
};
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to my random color slot game!</h1>
<button onclick="inputNum()">click to play</button>
<div>
  <div class="pick" id="one"></div>
  <div class="pick"></div>
  <div class="pick"></div>
  <div class="pick"></div>
  <div class="pick"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i had a completely different solution. When you use that code all the colors will be the same.

Comment: @liam robertson I added a second solution.